# Return Statement fails to execute

Tags: authentication, c#-4.0

I am trying to authenticate my User by retrieving the username and password from my database.

In the login function, I am trying to query the password which matches with the username which is passed as a parameter to the function and accordingly authenticate the user if the password matches with the user password.

**sqlDr.HasRows** returns True if there is any row affected. so if its True, I am going through my row in the table. On checking with the "password_" column of my Table, if it matches with the user password, it must returns true but here it simply returns false.

But the program returns false if the password doesn't match.

```
public bool login(string username,string password)
    {
        bool doesExist = false ;
        try
        {
            sqlConnection_ = DBConnection.openConnection();
            string query_login = "select password_ from Customer where username_=@username"; 
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query_login, sqlConnection_);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value=username;
            //sqlCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value = username; 
            SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();


            while (sqlDr.Read())
            {
                if (sqlDr.GetSqlString(0).ToString().Equals(password))
                {
                    doesExist = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        //DBConnection.closeConnection(sqlConnection_);
        //Console.WriteLine("I am here outside ");
        return doesExist;
    }
```

I am expecting my function to return True if the password matches.And returns false if the entered username or password doesn't match with any of the records present in my database.

Comment: As an aside you know you can use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` to obtain a single value from the database without needing to open a reader?

Comment: Just step through the code with your debugger and see why its failing? Much easier than us trying to guess.

Comment: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue` already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Larnu  **sqlCommand.Parameters["@username"].Value=username** is a better alternative?

Comment: No `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType,NVarChar).value = username;` (assumed username is an `nvarchar`) would be better. The article I linked explains.

Comment: @SubhamoyPaul, specify the data type and maximum length of your column. A `varchar(30)` example: `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@username",SqlDbType,VarChar, 30).value = username;`

Comment: You should check your code. Press F9 at the line when comparing is being made. Your code implies that passwords are saved as a plain text.